# Convert double[] to double* in c#

Tags: c#, pointers

How to convert `double[]` to `double*` in c#

I was trying

```
unsafe {
 System.Double[] a = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
 fixed(double *aP = a)
   for (int i = 0; i < a.Length ; i++)
   {
    //need to copy?
   }
}
```

Comment: @ErikTheViking: You are incorrect. C# does allow pointers in an unsafe context under certain conditions. For example, you can pin an array and get a pointer to it.

Comment: @AsfK: That is also incorrect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28k1s2k6.aspx. Your example uses `double *p = &a[0]` (not `a[0]` as you have, that would be a `double`), which is the same as `double *p = a`.

Comment: OP, what problem are you having exactly?  Are you getting a compiler error?  if so, what is it?  Is it telling you that you have to enable unsafe code in your compiler options? To do that, go to your project properties, Build, "Allow unsafe code".  As it stands your "question" doesn't even contain a question mark.

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do with this `double*`? Are you planning on passing it to an external Win32 or native function P/Invoke, or to a COM object? If so, this solution will not be enough.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan that is absolutely right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plays nice in my (very limited, ran it once) testing.

```
  unsafe { 
    Double[] a = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    fixed (double* aP = a) {
      for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
        System.Console.WriteLine(*aP + i);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have a hunch that the OP just needs to pass the correct compiler flag

Comment: @EdS. That makes sense actually, didn't think of that.